# Use i18n with variables on angular

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I'm trying to translate the values of a variable using i18n in angular, but I can't get those values on the xlf file.

I have this text in my html file:

`<p i18n="sidebar item">{{ menuItem.title }}</p>`

And i want to translate the value of that variable, but when I run the ng extract-i18n, I get this file:

```
<trans-unit id="8e0d2154f0f99d6356a491ebf5f7b3c96b2ab846" datatype="html">
        <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ menuItem.title }}"/></source>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/components/sidebar/sidebar.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">19</context>
        </context-group>
        <note priority="1" from="description">Sidebar item</note>
      </trans-unit>
```

I couldn't find any way to get the value of that variable to translate it independently.